# How to use TypeTag correctly if the type to match also takes type parameters

Tags: scala

I want to treat a sequence of vectors as a matrix. Obviously we have two cases which we need to distinct. Is it a sequence of row vectors or is it a sequence of column vectors. But the vectors by itself can be of any fractional type. So I have tried this:

```
implicit class MatrixEvent[K: Ordering, V: Fractional, T <: VectorEvent[K, V]](x: Seq[T])(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]) {
    lazy val mx = tag.tpe match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[ColumnVectorEvent[K, V]] =>
        x.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(new Array2DRowRealMatrix(x(0).vector.getRowDimension, x.length))({case (mx, (vec, idx)) => {
          mx.setColumnVector(idx, vec.vector.getColumnVector(0))
          mx
        }})
      case t if t =:= typeOf[RowVectorEvent[K, V]] =>
        x.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(new Array2DRowRealMatrix(x.length, x(0).vector.getColumnDimension))({case (mx, (vec, idx)) => {
          mx.setRowVector(idx, vec.vector.getRowVector(0))
          mx
        }})
    }
  }
```

But the scala compiler does not like this very much:

```
Error:(52, 29) No TypeTag available for ColumnVectorEvent[K,V]
      case t if t =:= typeOf[ColumnVectorEvent[K, V]] =>
```

Comment: Are you matching only on the outer type? You can just use `ClassTag` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do, but why would you bother using runtime logic and matching on types like that when you can opt for implicits? Unless I am missing something.

Let's assume your ADT looks something like this:

```
trait VectorEvent[K, V]
trait ColumnVectorEvent[K, V] extends VectorEvent[K, V]
trait RowEvent[K, V] extends VectorEvent[K, V]
trait Compute[T <: VectorEvent[K, V], K, V] {
  def compute(ev: T): Array2DRowRealMatrix
}

object Compute {
  implicit def rowEventCmp[K, V]: Compute[RowEvent[K, V], K, V]] = {
   new Compute {
     def compute: Array2DRowRealMatrix = {
       x.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(new Array2DRowRealMatrix(x(0).vector.getRowDimension, x.length))({case (mx, (vec, idx)) => {
      mx.setColumnVector(idx, vec.vector.getColumnVector(0))
      mx
    }})
     }
   }
  }
  implict def columnVectorEvent[K, V] = ...
}
```

And then finally you can leverage the typeclass instances. Scala will know how to look in the companion object of `Compute` by default to search for those implicits.

```
implicit class MatrixEvent[
  K: Ordering,
  V: Fractional,
  T <: VectorEvent[K, V]
](x: Seq[T])(implicit ev: Compute[T, K, V]) {
    lazy val mx = ev.compute
  }
```